# Django Query not working under cron job

Tags: python, django, cron

I want to create a cron job in django user for sending emails to users.

```
all_user_result = AssesmentRegisterdUser.objects.filter(finish_mail = False)
for asm_user in all_user_result:
    email = asm_user.student.email
    full_name = asm_user.student.username
    module_name = asm_user.test.module_name
    test_finish_mail(to_email = email, full_name = full_name, module_name = module_name)
    asm_user.finish_mail = True
    asm_user.save()
```

when i try this code under job, it is not able to retrieve(using foreign key relation) `asm_user.student.user.email` and `asm_user.test.module_name` from my database.

> Note: Cron job is working with static data.

Comment: Maybe you should post the models.

Comment: I follow this approach for my jobs:  1-create a django management command  2-Call python manage.py command_name in hash script

Comment: so you are telling inside the cron database query not working ?  Are you sure `all_user_result` will have some value when using python bash

Comment: yes , Note: Cron job is working with static data.
ex: email = 'example.com' ...etc
and asm_user.finish_mail = True is also reflect on db